# How to setup routes in subfolder? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really struggling how to setup controller which are placed in subfolder? I already tried below but I got an error in my console. Somebody helped how to achieve and fix this, I'm from laravel and I using rails now.

Error in my console:

> 'Api/Auth/register' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.

My target route is this below:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register
```

Below image is directory where I place the `register_controller`

[image]

Here's inside of my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'Api' do
    namespace 'Auth' do
      get 'register', to: 'register#store'
    end
  end
end
```

And in my **register_controller.rb** is below:

```
module Api
  module Auth
    class RegisterController < ApplicationController
      def store
        render json: { code: 200, data: 'sample' }, status: :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a namespace for your controller, and then a route for each of your actions (methods in your controllers). Also, the namespace is usually lower case.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'auth' do
      namespace 'register' do
        get 'store'
      end
    end
  end
end
```